# Comparing two arrays and can't get it to return true

Tags: javascript

My objective is to compare the two arrays. I can't get it return false, it just compares the first values and returns. Am I not asking it correctly to loop through all values before determining true or false?

```
var array1 =[1,2,3];
var array2=[1,2,4];

var areArraysSame = function(array1, array2) {
   if(array1.length !== array2.length) {
       return "These are not the same length";
   }
   for(var i = 0; i <= array1.length; i++) {
      if(array1[i] !== array2[i]) {
      return "These are not the same array";

      }else{
      return "these are the same array";
      }
     }
    };
   console.log(areArraysSame(array1, array2));
```

Comment: It will never return false because it always returns a string value.  Also, you are always returning after comparing only the first item in both arrays.

Comment: One problem I see is the else statement. What you're currently saying is if the current element in each array is the same as the other, then the arrays the same. This only executes for one iteration because you immediately return a value. You should only need to return false if the two elements are not the same. If the function makes it to the end of the for loop, you know all elements were the same, and thus, return true.

Comment: To build on what @WillP. said, you should take a look at what JavaScript considers [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) because it isn't always 100% intuitive.

Answer (score 2):

You are not waiting for all comparisons to take place before returning `true` (*or your true string*)

You should do this:

```
for(var i = 0; i <= array1.length; i++) {
    if(array1[i] !== array2[i]) {
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

Wait for the loop to end before returning `true`

Answer (score 1):

You are returning immediately after checking the first value, remove the else block in the for loop such that it compares all the values as shown below :

```
var array1 =[1,2,3];
var array2=[1,2,4];

var areArraysSame = function(array1, array2) {
 if(array1.length !== array2.length) {
   return "These are not the same length";
 }
for(var i = 0; i <= array1.length; i++) {
  if(array1[i] !== array2[i]) {
   return "These are not the same array";
  }
 }
 return "These are the same array";
};
console.log(areArraysSame(array1, array2));
```

Comment: I was updating the same :) @Keiwan

Comment: Thanks this works - i understand now I needed put the return for true outside the loop.

Comment: @suzo Yeah, I saw your edit, that's why I deleted my comment again :)

Answer (score 0):

Return will stop your loop and exit the function. So since in the above code your first element for both arrays is 1 the code returns on the first iteration of the loop. If you want to return whether or not the arrays match return after the loop and use a boolean variable to keep track of whether or not the arrays match. Only return in the loop on a false statement.

Answer (score 0):

You have a return statement in the first iteration of your for loop; after the first item in each array is compared your loop will end whether it's true or false.

You can store a condition and base your return on that.

```
    var array1 = [1, 2, 3];
    var array2 = [1, 2, 4];

    var areArraysSame = function (array1, array2) {
        var isSame = true;

        if (array1.length !== array2.length) {
            return "These are not the same length";
        }

        for (var i = 0; i <= array1.length; i++) {
            if (array1[i] !== array2[i]) {
                isSame = false;
            }
        }
        return isSame ? "These are the same array" : "These are not the same array";
    };

    console.log(areArraysSame(array1, array2));
```